# Formula Explanation Excel 2016 "--"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I was doing research in how to use a formula and someone provided me with the following: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(A2:A15)=2010),--(B2:B15>=50))`

The person has not responded in over a week and I was wondering if anyone could explain the purpose of using the `--` before the ranges? Is this in relation to using Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: This was answered a while ago over on Superuser: [https://superuser.com/a/1089109](https://superuser.com/a/1089109) (since that is a different Stack Exchange site than Stack Overflow, I'm just adding the link here instead of downvoting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--` turns a range of logical values (e.g. `TRUE`/`FALSE`) to a range of numerical values (e.g. `1`/`0`). This is necessary in order for `SUMPRODUCT` to work as intended. It has nothing to do with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Another alternative is to use `+0`, e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A2:A15)=2010)+0,(B2:B15>=50)+0)
```

In this case, not even necessary to do either. Could just do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A2:A15)=2010)*(B2:B15>=50))
```

All three of these alternatives will return the same result.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, it may be useful in other formula like an if statement using a `Sum(If(...))`

Comment: There's a ton of examples on SO that use this `--` or `+0`. Wouldn't take too long of searching through the "excel-formula" tag to find some examples.